# C++ VTK reading and saving data from several files

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am new to VTK and my goal is to be able to store information from several files into a vector so then I can separately use filters on some files or show it on QVTKWidget.

My question is what type of vector should I create?

So far I have this: 
class for Reader that are creating my reader and pushing it back:

```
template<class TReader> vtkDataSet *readVTKfile(std::string fileName)
{
   vtkSmartPointer<TReader> reader =
       vtkSmartPointer<TReader>::New();
   reader->SetFileName(fileName.c_str());
   reader->Update();
   reader->GetOutput()->Register(reader);
   return vtkDataSet::SafeDownCast(reader->GetOutput());
}
```

And here is the problem with how can I use it for my vector:

```
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Choose"), "", tr("Vtk files (*.vtk)"));
std::vector<std::string> inputFilenames(filenames.count());
if (!filenames.isEmpty())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.count(); i++)
        inputFilenames.push_back(filenames.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData());
}

std::vector<vtkDataSet*> data(inputFilenames.size()); // what type it should be?

for (int i = 0; i < inputFilenames.size(); i++)
{
    data[i] = readVTKfile<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>(inputFilenames[i]);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> objectMapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

//objectMapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
objectMapper->SetInputConnection(data[0]); // so then I can use it for example for showing?

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> objectActor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
objectActor->SetMapper(objectMapper);

// VTK Renderer
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(objectActor);

// VTK/Qt wedded
this->qvtkWidgetLeft->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Choose"), "", tr("Vtk files (*.vtk)"));
```

// use the range based for, and .toStdString if you wanna std::string from QString

```
std::vector<std::string> inputFilenames(filenames.count());
for(const auto& filename : filenames) {
        inputFilenames.push_back(filename.toStdString());
}
```

// I'm not sure if this is the right type, but it's what the documentation uses

```
std::vector<vtkAlgorithmOutput*> data(inputFilenames.size());

for (int i = 0; i < inputFilenames.size(); i++)
{
    data[i] = readVTKfile<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>(inputFilenames[i]);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> objectMapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

objectMapper->SetInputConnection(data[0]); 

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> objectActor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
objectActor->SetMapper(objectMapper);

// VTK Renderer
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(objectActor);

// VTK/Qt wedded
this->qvtkWidgetLeft->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: My question was about data vector not about imputFilenames

Comment: @Julia.G, my reply was just mistyped, you should use vtkAlgorithmOutput* on the data vector.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, Im trying to use vtkAlgorithmOutput as you suggested, but I still don't know what should I use to convert information from reader into that

Comment: okay, so I've just solved the problem with using dynamic_cast to make vtkAlgorithmOutput out of PolyData from reader output